# Strange behavior with float:right and css hover

Tags: html, css, hover, css-float

I have this page http://myrender.altervista.org/show2.html

I moved the 5 buttons to the right corner with the `float:right` instruction and then the hover in those buttons stopped to work suddently (before the `float:right` it worked).

There is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
        <div class="latest">Ultimi Caricamenti</div>
        <img class="imgslide" src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttondiv">
        <div class="button" onclick="change(0); clearInterval(t);" id="p0"></div>
        <div class="button" onclick="change(1); clearInterval(t);" id="p1"></div>
        <div class="button" onclick="change(2); clearInterval(t);" id="p2"></div>
        <div class="button" onclick="change(3); clearInterval(t);" id="p3"></div>
        <div class="button" onclick="change(4); clearInterval(t);" id="p4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and there are the CSS classes (only the needed):

```
.button
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background:#eee;
    border-radius:50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.button:hover
{
    opacity:1.0;
}

.buttondiv
{
    margin-top: -17px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float:right;
}

.buttonactive
{
    background:#1390cd;
    opacity:0.8;
}

.container
{
    width:592px;
    height:183px;
}
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: *> the hover in those buttons stopped to work* - How stopped? Still become white on hover (FF37)

Comment: now it works good, thanks to Kay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `position: relative;` to `.buttondiv` or to `.button`

Comment: Also had to add `z-index: (any value)` to make it work.